# .net Razor ajax duplicating view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

i'm trying to use ajax in my simple test app. I have one drop down list, one button and one div where i present the items picked from the drop down. Here is the code:

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["items"] == null)
        {
            Session["items"] = new List<Item>();
        }

        var items = new Item[] { 
            new Item("1", "one"),
            new Item("2", "two"),
            new Item("3", "three")
        };

        ViewBag.list = Session["items"];
        ViewBag.items = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Value");
        return View(new Item());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Item item)
    {
        ((List<Item>)Session["items"]).Add(item);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    private string id;
    private string value;

    public Item(string id, string value)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Item()
    {
    }

    public string Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
    public string Value { get { return value; } set { this.value = value; } }
}
```

My view:

```
@model TestExample.Models.Item
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "itemList" }))
{
  <div id="btn">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, ViewBag.items as SelectList)
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  </div>
}

<div id="itemList">
  @foreach (TestExample.Models.Item item in ViewBag.list as     List<TestExample.Models.Item>)
  {
    <h1>@item.Value</h1>
  }
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever i pick item from the list and press add i get my drop box and button duplicated and the items that are show in the div. This happens after the first click and after it i always see two drop boxes and buttons, and the items in the list are duplicated.. What is the cause to this? How can i fix it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After ajax post you insert same page into:

```
<div id="itemList">
  ...
</div>
```

That's why you have 2 buttons and etc. In this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Item item) { ... }
```

You need to return partial view only with your list items.

Comment: i just thought of that but i did't know for sure. So i need to make partial view, fill ViewBag.list with the items i need to render in it and return that view...

Thanks ill try it :)